# Implementing PSD processing in web (like in society6.com)

Tags: image-processing, web, photoshop, psd

Is there a Windows server with Photoshop running that process all these templates? It just happens too quickly. How did they achieve that? 
I've been looking for the answer for quite a long time and didn't find anything worthy.

[image: https://gyazo.com/4603e7a613152f0eb02fa7f716b20db4]

Comment: The products (and their geometries) are the same right, it's just the texture (uploaded image) that changes. If these previews are static there's probably no need to render them at runtime...I wonder if you can get away with normal and displacement maps

Answer (score 0):

A way something like this would be done would be to have an overlay template that you'd place your image under and then all of the shading and such would would go on top of it. Then it's just a mater of rotating and skewing the angle of the picture underneath the overlay to get the right perspective. This can be done programmatically in a language of your choice like [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php), [Python](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/image_processing/#geometrical-transformations), [C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're describing may be achieved using the [Adobe Photoshop API](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/api/). Click on try demo and take a look at the various options, including the Smart Object demo.